# Load column data into comboBox

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I have a `Datagridview` that has some data from excel file. I have one `ComboBox` that must show a specific column data from `Datagridview`. How can I do that? Thank you.

I have tried this with no results:

```
private void comboBox5_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox5.Items.Clear();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewNE.Rows)
    {
        comboBox5.Items.Add(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Why are you clearing all the items on selection change? And are you using WinForms?

Comment: If user update datagridview, I think it must clear old values. I am wrong? I am using WinForms.

Comment: Can you be more informative about the problem you are facing ?

Comment: I just need to populate ComboBox with a specifc column from Datagridview.

Comment: My apologies. I am still confused with the code . On what action you want to populate the combo box.?  On changing combo box selection what should happen ? As i see, you are clearing your collection on each selection change and filling the same data . I guess, during loading of form or view, you should be populating the items and on selection change you should be performing your intended actions

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I have solved:

```
private void ComboBox5_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewNE.Rows)
    {
        comboBox5.Items.Add(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
    }
```